# How do I get Wi-Fi info from within Terminal?

Tags: command-line, wifi

Is there a way to get BSSID and the list of available Wi-Fi networks from within Terminal?

I.e. I'm looking for something similar to `ifconfig run0 scan` on OpenBSD, which lists all access points, BSSID, signal strength etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's an airport utility buried that you'll want to use. Create a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin to the utility for quick access with this command:

`sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport`

Now, you should be able to run `airport -s` and get a list of available networks with BSSIDs.

If you hold the option key while opening the WiFi networks in the Menu Bar, you can also see the BSSIDs one at a time, although it seems like you wanted the CLI-like version from OpenBSD.

**UPDATE:**

"rootless" AKA System Integrity Protection (SIP) has been added to OSX since I wrote this answer originally, which makes `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` *read-only*. It is proper to use `/usr/local/bin`, so I have updated the answer so that the symbolic link is created there.

Comment: Better than creating a symlink would likely be to create an alias in your shell initialization. `alias airport="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport"` Doesn't need sudo privileges hence is available for non-admin users alike and doesn't affect other users.

Comment: 1) "Better" is relative. If you are the only user of a Mac, then non-admin users and other users are not a concern, and having the command linked somewhere in your $PATH which means you can use it in other scripts and shells (although I'd opt to link it to /usr/local/bin/). 2) The `airport` command has been at that path at least since 10.6 and possibly earlier, for people who are concerned about backwards compatibility. It is still there in 10.8 as well.

Comment: I suggested the symbolic link for the same reason TJ suggested, because you have got to have it linked to your $PATH, so I figured maybe the symbolic link would be less likely to give issues. Plus, many users do not use (or know how to use) .profile or .bash_profile. Both solutions work perfectly well :)

Answer (score 4):

It's now 2024 (MacOS Sonoma 14.4) and running `airport` gets you a deprecation message:

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -s

WARNING: The airport command line tool is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
For diagnosing Wi-Fi related issues, use the Wireless Diagnostics app or wdutil command line tool.
```

What you *can* do is use the suggested `wdutil` (the CLI version of `Wireless Diagnostics.app`):

```
sudo wdutil info |grep "BSSID"

    BSSID                : 9a:37:2e:2d:cb:b4
```

Comment: For the part about getting a list of available networks, you might look at the command `networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0` as a place to start.  (For me it seems to dump a list of all known/saved WiFi networks.)  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313282/qt-read-the-list-of-ssid-for-macos

Comment: Is there any alternative which works without sudo?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is still correct, but due to new security measures in macOS Monterey, you will now need to run the `airport -s` command with `sudo` to print all the info, mainly BSSIDs and country codes. The same goes for the `airport -I` command, if you want macOS to print your connected gateway's BSSID.

Unless there are third-party tools that somehow work around this without privilege escalation—I don't know any—, a manual workaround is possible with LaunchDaemons in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. These would then dump the `airport` outputs into temporary files for the user to `cat`.

(1) Possible LaunchDaemon for `airport -s` (e.g. `local.$USER.wifi.plist`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.$USER.wifi</string>
    <key>LowPriorityBackgroundIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -s 2&gt;/dev/null &gt; /private/var/tmp/wifi.dump</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.$USER.wifi.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.$USER.wifi.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>900</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(2) Possible LaunchDaemon for `airport -I` (e.g. `local.$USER.airport.plist`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.$USER.airport</string>
    <key>LowPriorityBackgroundIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I 2&gt;/dev/null &gt; /private/var/tmp/airport.dump</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.$USER.airport.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/local.$USER.airport.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>900</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Obviously you need to replace `$USER` with your local username. These daemons are set to run every 15 minutes, which you can change, of course.

The daemons both write to `/var/tmp` instead of `/tmp` because afaik the former path's contents will survive a reboot.

After the daemon setup, you can then just run `cat /private/var/tmp/wifi.dump` instead of `sudo airport -s` or `cat /private/var/tmp/airport.dump` instead of `sudo airport -I`.

Nota bene: if you want your connected gateway's MAC address, which is (usually slightly) different from the BSSID, this is one possible command:

`arp -a 2>/dev/null | head -1 | awk -F")" '{print $NF}' | sed -e "s/^ at //" -e "s/ on .*//"`

Answer (score 1):

Now that `airport` is showing as deprecated, here is a command that does not require `sudo` to get the current SSID:

`networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'`

Replace `en0` with your wireless network interface.