# List wireless connection information in terminal

Tags: macos, wifi

In OSX if you hold down the Option key and click on the wireless icon in the menu bar it will show details of the wifi connection - speed, BSSID ,channel etc.

Can this information be listed in the terminal?

Comment: I came here looking for basically the same information, but TIL Option-Click!  This opens a whole new world of macOS understanding for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with the following command:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing missing is the band in brackets after channel (5Ghz) so pretty close :)

Comment: @codecowboy I guess you can infer from the channel (i.e. my output is channel 48, so it's 5 GHz)?

Comment: Does this work on MacOS Monterey? BSSID is empty for me. Used to be present before I upgraded.

Comment: Now only possible with `sudo airport -I`. Same for the `-s` argument: `sudo airport -s` in order to get the WiFi environment including BSSIDs and country codes.

Comment: Posted a workaround with LaunchDaemons here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457129/196293